# is it possible to combine seperate pattern groups to one group in regex

Tags: php, regex

for example:

```
"I am living in Germany." - (I\sam)\sliving\s(in\sGermany)
```

This gives

```
1 - I am
2 - in Germany
```

Is it possible to get the String "I am in Germany" from preg_match ?

Comment: Just use `preg_replace` with [`'~(I\sam\s)living\s(in\sGermany)~'` regex and `'\1\2'` as replacement](https://ideone.com/SkmmIY). You cannot match non-continuous text within one match operation.

Comment: normally i would do something like that, but the problem is, i have to work with a formular where i can only pass one match for the endresult. I think i have to expand the formular for this case. Thank you

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not possible to achieve that with one match operation. Either match with 2 capturing groups and then concatenate, or you have to match several times with different patterns and again concatenate. The simplest way is using a regex-based replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match non-continuous text within one match operation.

Instead, you can use `preg_replace` with capturing groups around those subpatterns that you want to keep, and restore them in the replacement pattern with backreferences.

So, use

Regex: `'~(I\sam\s)living\s(in\sGermany)~'`

Replacement: `'\1\2'`

See [demo](https://ideone.com/SkmmIY).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get output without regex:

```
$mystr  = "I am living in Germany.";
$res = str_replace(".", "", "".join(explode("living ", $mystr)));
print $res;
```